# How do I stop the spinning cursor in a long process

Tags: c#

I wrote a C# program that lets a user drag and drop a file name from a folder into a text box, after that the program will then run a long process to search all the subdirectory(s) for the name. The problem I have is when it does that, it change the cursor to the "+" and I can't do anything else in that folder.  Is there a way to not having the cursor change to "+" and let the user continue working in that folder? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you are using winforms, you should use another thread different than the UI to do the long task. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a link you can read about a visual studio component that allows you to easily do this, called BackgroundWorker. But basically, in the `DoWrok` event, you do the long task and in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event you do whatever you want to do when the long task finishes.